# Sweetalert2 not working after add js scroll

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sweetalert2

i'm using sweetalert and it's running without any issues, but when i add jsscroll to the data using loop, it (sweetalert) doesn't work.

The first data before scrolling can show sweetalert, but when the second data appears after scrolling and I press the button again to display (sweetalert) it doesn't work.
Please help me.

js scroll

```
$('ul.pagination').hide();
$(function() {
   $('.infinite-scroll').jscroll({
       autoTrigger: true,
       loadingHtml: '<div class="sk-three-bounce"><div class="sk-child sk-bounce1"></div><div class="sk-child sk-bounce3"></div><div class="sk-child sk-bounce2"></div></div>',
           
       nextSelector: '.pagination li.active + li a',
       contentSelector: 'div.infinite-scroll',
       callback: function() {
               $('ul.pagination').remove();
       }
   });
});
```

sweetalert

```
$('.__sweet_edit').on('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     const self = $(this);
     const placeId = $(this).attr("data-place_id");
     const placeName = $(this).attr("data-place_name");
     const urlEdit = $(this).attr("data-url_edit");
     const dateName = $(this).attr("data-date_name");
     const urlDestroy = $(this).attr("data-url_delete");
     Swal.fire({
         title: placeName,
         html: `<x-sweet-alerts.edit></x-sweet-alerts.edit>`,
         icon: 'question',
         showCancelButton: false,
         showConfirmButton: false,
         allowOutsideClick: false,
         allowEscapeKey: false,
         showCloseButton: true,
         confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
         cancelButtonColor: '#cccccc',
         confirmButtonText: 'Button',
         cancelButtonText: 'Cancel'
    });

});
```

Comment: Pls provide full code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling the script correctly...

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```